# What's the relation of entropy with synchronisation?

Tags: classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, thought-experiment

2 pendulums tied to a same rod and oscillating with different frequencies and phases synchronize over time. This could be done at home just to see how interesting it is that things try to sync their work with others by any possible medium(in this case, the rod). But i just wonder that what happens to their entropy, both pendulums had different entropy but by the time they started oscillating similarly.

Plz answer this question too: when can i use my own tags for question? I couldn't find tags, like pendulum, synchronize, for this question.

Comment: Which of the many defintions of entropy are you asking about?

Comment: I mean the measure of randomness or disorder spread in a system. How much chaos the system has.

Answer (score 2):

[Pendulum synchronization](https://physicsworld.com/a/the-secret-of-the-synchronized-pendulums/) happens because of energy exchange between two oscillators. In a perfectly frictionless, isolated system this would not increase entropy at all, and the pendulums would keep on going into and out of phase forever.

Technically, when one formulates a mathematical model of the system (like the Lagrangian in equation 4.1. in [(Bennett et al. 2002)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3067433)) this doesn't shrink volumes in phase space if the model is conservative, and hence the energy exchange just produces endlessly cycling behavior. But if one introduces friction (as in equations 4.2 and 4.3) then phase space volume will shrink and there will be one attractor state - pendulums that just hang still.

In this case it is fairly clear that the physical entropy has increased: the original information about the pendulum phases (and their energy) gradually gets lost due to friction. The entropy increase happens in heating of the joints of the pendulums, a microscopic effect that the above mathematical model doesn't model. One could say that besides the macroscopic pendulums there are zillions of atomic pendulums that gradually gets disorganized by heating, and the information in the original state now is irreversibly lost into their states.

Bennett et al. also include a kick mechanism feeding more energy into the pendulums (equation 4.6). This serves to keep them moving, and prevents the static state from being an attractor state. Now we have a dissipative system (phase space volumes shrink due to friction) but fed energy; the result in this case is that there are different limit cycles (synchronized, anti-synchronized, beating death) that are approached (which one depends on the parameters). During a limit cycle the energy gained is also dissipated, producing more entropy.